# SQL query involving comparison of sets

Tags: mysql, sql, database

### Background

Products can be sold as bundles. Following tables are present: `products`, `bundles`, `bundles_products`, `orders`, `orders_products`.

An order would be said to "contain" a bundle if it contains all the bundle's products.

### Problem

How would one go about counting orders for bundles?

### Example

**products** table

```
id  name
1   broom
2   mug
3   spoon
4   candle
```

**bundles** table

```
id  name
1   dining
2   witchcraft
```

**bundles_products** table

```
bundle_id product_id
1         2
1         3
2         1
2         4
```

**orders_products** table

```
order_id  product_id
1000      1
1000      3
1001      1
1001      2
1001      3
```

The query would return the following table:

```
bundle     orders
dining     1
witchcraft 0
```

### Notes

The example intentionally misses the `orders` table as it is not relevant what it contains.

Of course, this could be approached imperatively, by writing some code and gathering the data, but I was hoping there is a declarative, SQL way of querying for this kind of things?

One idea I had was to use a `GROUP_CONCAT` to concatenate all the products of a bundle and somehow compare that with products of each order. Still, a long way from clear.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  How are overlaps between bundles handled (say "A", "B", and "C" are in one bundle and "A" and "B" are in another).

Comment: *"I was hoping there is a declarative, SQL way of querying for this kind of things?"* There is as SQL is a declarative language.. *"Still, a long way from clear."* i advice you to read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) as the problem/question is a long way from clear to us to.

Comment: noted. providing example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use two [Derived Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) (subqueries). In first subquery, we will fetch the total number of unique products for every bundle. In the second subquery, we will fetch the total products in an order, for a combination of order and bundle.

We will `LEFT JOIN` them on `bundle_id` as well as matching the total count of products per bundle in them. Eventually, we will do a grouping on bundle, and count the number of orders matching successfully.

```
SELECT dt1.id              AS bundle_id,
       dt1.name            AS bundle,
       Count(dt2.order_id) AS orders
FROM   (SELECT b.id,
               b.name,
               Count(DISTINCT bp.product_id) AS total_bundle_products
        FROM   bundles AS b
               JOIN bundles_products AS bp
                 ON bp.bundle_id = b.id
        GROUP  BY b.id,
                  b.name) AS dt1
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT op.order_id,
                         bp.bundle_id,
                         Count(DISTINCT op.product_id) AS order_bundle_products
                  FROM   orders_products AS op
                         JOIN bundles_products AS bp
                           ON bp.product_id = op.product_id
                  GROUP  BY bp.bundle_id,
                            op.order_id) AS dt2
              ON dt2.bundle_id = dt1.id
                 AND dt2.order_bundle_products = dt1.total_bundle_products
GROUP  BY dt1.id,
          dt1.name
```

**[SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7926f0/6)**

Answer (score 0):

Here's the brief example, which lacks some parts, I omitted because I don't know precise database structure. Logic is such:

1. Temp table is generated, which consists of 3 rows - order, count of
   products related to bundle, count of products in bundle
2. Then we select only orders from this table in which we have those last two
       variables equal

```
select count(order_id) from orders 
    left join(
        select count(*) from bundles_products as bundle_amount, 
                  sum(case when orders_products in (
                  select names from bundles_products where bundle_id='1') then 1 else 0) as order_total, 
                  orders.order_id 
            left join product on bundle_products.product_id = products.product_id
            left join orders on products.product_id = orders_products.product_id
        where bundle_products.bundle_id ='1'
        ) as my_table 
        on orders.order_name = my_table.orders 
        where my_table.bundle_amount = my_table.order_total
```

Edit: I posted this as a response to previous version of the question, without detailed explanation.

Edit2: fixed query a bit. It can be starting point. Logic is still the same, you can get amount of orders for each bundle_id using it